# Issue adding has_many to ActiveModel::Serializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, active-model-serializers

I've been trying to add has_many relationships to my ActiveModel::Serializers for a while now and I'm getting a bevy of errors related to them. It seems like the has_many relationships are calling the wrong serializer. Here is the error:

```
Started GET "/vehicles/1001" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-04-11 01:07:08 -0700
Processing by UsersController#index as JSON
  Parameters: {"user"=>{}}
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.2ms)[0m  [1mSELECT `users`.* FROM `users` [0m
Processing by VehiclesController#show as JSON
Completed 200 OK in 1ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1001", "vehicle"=>{}}
  [1m[35mVehicle Load (0.6ms)[0m  SELECT `vehicles`.* FROM `vehicles` WHERE `vehicles`.`id` = 1001 LIMIT 1


Started GET "/vendor_reps" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-04-11 01:07:08 -0700
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `serializable_hash' for #<ActiveModel::ArraySerializer:0x007fbbcaa82018>):
  app/controllers/vehicles_controller.rb:20:in `block (2 levels) in show'
  app/controllers/vehicles_controller.rb:18:in `show'


Processing by VendorRepsController#index as JSON
  Parameters: {"vendor_rep"=>{}}
  [1m[35mVendorRep Load (0.3ms)[0m  SELECT `vendor_reps`.* FROM `vendor_reps` 
Completed 200 OK in 2ms (Views: 0.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)
  Rendered /Users/pzuraq/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (2.3ms)
  Rendered /Users/pzuraq/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered /Users/pzuraq/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (11.7ms)
```

The code is gisted here: https://gist.github.com/pzuraq/5361607

Comment: You can remove the `active_model_serializer`, it's not necessary if your Model has the same name as the Serializer (e.g. `Option => OptionSerializer`)

Comment: Yes but that doesn't solve the issue... I added that to see if it changed anything actually but it doesn't.

Answer (score 5):

So it turns out that using :option as a property name was causing conflicts. There are probably other conflicting names as well. Gotta be careful about the namespace!