# Error with associations using Active Model Serializers

Tags: active-model-serializers

When rendering the json of a model with nested associations I get the following error:

```
undefined method `serializable_hash' for #<ActiveModel::ArraySerializer:0x007fe761592d88>
```

This is my code:

```
class EventSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :date

  has_many :markets
end

class MarketSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :bet_limit_time

  has_many :options
end

class OptionSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :odds
end
```

The error appears when rendering the options association.

It's a pretty simple case, but I have found no issue about it.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? Have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a problem with having an attribute named `options`.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/16005874/157943:

> "It turns out that using :option as a property name was causing conflicts. There are probably other conflicting names as well. Gotta be careful about the namespace!"

Not sure how to fix it other than renaming the `options` association (possibly you could build it manually by overriding `#attributes` and constructing the hash manually?)